# Google Slides - Adding drop shadow to an image

Tags: drop-shadow, google

[image]Any idea on how to add a drop shadow to an element on Goolge Slides? I have googled a lot and found a couple of websites explaining how to add a drop shadow to a text but no leads on how to add it to an element. I saw a slide which had drop shadow and saved it for [reference](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1kgtbClef6BMXNjho2cN9FzeWNsxEsB-8mfqjacvmyd8/edit?usp=sharing) but couldn't find out the way to replicate it.

Comment: Are you sure the shadow isn't a separate image or part of the image? From what I have seen there is no feature in Google Slides that allows you to add a drop shadow.

Comment: Yes, I have added the link to the presentation, you can confirm it from there aswell. I searched alot for the feature, but wasnt able to find so thought of posting it here!

Comment: Very strange. All the help docs say there is no drop shadow. There is no drop shadow button or option that I can find... But, you can copy and paste that image to a new slide and there *is* a drop shadow style attached (i.e. it's not part of the image or another image image).

Comment: No idea how the drop shadow was created but you can copy/paste that image then "replace image" and the replaced image will keep the drop-shadow https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhLH7.png

Comment: @cai yes but it is more like a clipping mask if you replace the image. So an image having more width or height would be clipped if replaced.

Comment: @EbtihajKhan you can reset the frame to the correct size easy enough

Comment: @cai already tried that. Slides stop saving the material and asks you to revert the image to an older version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One work around so you can use the effect on other images is to use the "Paint format" button to copy the effect. Select the image with the shadow, click the "Paint format" button, then click another image you want the shadow on.

Another work around is to copy the image and "replace image", which will switch out the photo but keep the shadow.

Comment: Nice idea you had for "replace image" there ;)

Comment: I figured that functionality was assumed originally :P

Comment: The replace image it is more like a clipping mask. So an image having more width or height would be clipped if replaced.

Comment: The paint format button works perfectly :)

Answer (score 3):

Google Slides has caught up and you can now add drop shadow to images and shapes from the format menu:

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Thank you! I've been waiting for this feature for a while. Glad it made it in!

Answer (score 2):

You're not able to directly add drop shadows for images in Google Slides.

The drop shadow was made in a different slide making program like PowerPoint and the file was uploaded to the Drive. The user then opened the PowerPoint file with Slides and the shadow is stilled applied like it would be in PowerPoint.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is now standard available in Google slides for both images and shapes.

All you need to do is Right-click on the object > format options > drop shadow.

Answer (score 0):

Found a hack for this...

1) Copy the image from google sheets and paste to a doc in Keynote

2) add the required image shadow / borders / effects

3) Copy this new Keynote image and past back into Google Sheets